# Very surprising perfs of fprintf vs std::ofstream (fprintf is very slow)

Tags: c++, ofstream, printf

I was running some benchmarks to find the most efficient way to write a huge array to a file in C++ (more than 1Go in ASCII).

So I compared std::ofstream with fprintf (see the switch I used below)

```
    case 0: {
        std::ofstream out(title, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        if (out) {
            ok = true;
            for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    out<<A[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                out<<"\n";
            }
            out.close();
        } else {
            std::cout<<"Error with file : "<<title<<"\n";
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        FILE *out = fopen(title.c_str(), "w");
        if (out!=NULL) {
            ok = true;
            for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    fprintf(out, "%d ", A[i][j]);
                }
                fprintf(out, "\n");
            }
            fclose(out);
        } else {
            std::cout<<"Error with file : "<<title<<"\n";
        }
        break;
    }
```

And my huge problem is that fprintf seems to be more thant 12x slower compared to std::ofstream. Do you have an idea of what is the origin of the problem in my code ? Or maybe std::ofstream is very optimized compared to fprintf ?

(and an other question : do you know another faster way to write a file)

Thank you very much

(detail : I was compiling with g++ -Wall -O3)

Comment: i think you should use fputs instead of fprintf to get more similar behavior

Comment: also look at `ostream::write()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/

Comment: @AndersK.: No. fputs is the equivalent of a streambuf (unformatted); fprintf is the proper counterpart of ostream.

Comment: @MSalters why do you think that? fprintf contains a variable argument list processing whereas the operator<< on ostream doesn't. A better comparison would be with fputs.

Comment: I wonder what the size of the output buffers are in each case.

Comment: Hi, Vincent. I have two suggestions on how to improve the quality of the answers you recieve. 1) Please go back to your previous questions and accept the answers you find most useful. 2) Please create a minimal, complete program that we can compile and run that demonstrates your question. If we run this program fragment, we have to make assumptions about what the rest of the program does. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: If you're writing data to a file, a more efficient method is to write to a big buffer first, then use the block write functions to move from buffer to file.  This will reduce the number of I/O transactions and turn many little requests into one large requests (which hard drives prefer).

Comment: FWIW: [This program](http://ideone.com/aZW3v), derived from the OP's program fragment, takes essentially identical time to run either branch of the switch statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fprintf("%d"` requires runtime parsing of the format string, once per integer. `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, int)` is resolved by the compiler, once per compilation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `fprintf()` does have to do a bit more work at runtime, since it has to parse and process the format string. However, given the size of your output file I would expect those differences to be of little consequence, and would expect the code to be I/O bound.

I therefore suspect that your benchmark is flawed in some way.

1. Do you consistently get a 12x difference if you run the tests repeatedly?
2. What happens to the timings if you reverse the order in which you run the tests?
3. What happens if you call `fsync()/sync()` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

There is a file buffer in the ofstream, this may decrease the times accessing to the disk. in addition, fprintf is a function with variable parameters which will call some va_# functions, but ofstream won't.I think you can use fwrite() or putc() to have a test.

Comment: putc would be slower since it write one character only, it will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set sync_with_stdio somewhere upstream of the code you have shown?

While what you report is opposite that of what is empirically seen, most people think and believe what you see should be the norm.  iostreams are type-safe, whereas the printf family of functions are variadic functions that have to infer the types of the va_list from the format specifier.